# Set up simultaneous SSH keys for GitHub and BitBucket

Tags: git, github, ssh, mercurial, bitbucket

This will be a question and an answer together.

My goal is to have GitHub(via git) and BitBucket(via hg) co-exist on the same machine, both using SSH keys for all repos of each respective type.

Setup:
Windows 10
git-scm
tortoisehg

(Despite using Win 10, I'll be describing bash paths. Anywhere you see a "~", just replace that with "C:\users\yourName")

There are lots of other questions and answers on this, but none of them really pointed me in the direction I needed.

For me, GitHub is my "primary" and BitBucket is my "secondary"
This guide gets me the first ssh key, which I save as "id_rsa" in the "~/ssh" folder.
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

BitBucket is my secondary, and so I create a second key, with the custom name "bb_rsa"
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

And the answer will be the final step that makes it all work.

Comment: Technically you can use the same key for both. Documentation is usually written with new users in mind, though, so it's structured to include every setup step.

Comment: I heard that from multiple sources, and I actually tried that, but GitHub instructions describe a 4096 bit key, and the BitBucket instructions describe a 2048 bit key. I attempted to cross-register the keys, but neither would accept the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseHG uses `~/mercurial.ini` for the HG settings, but other mercurial installations might use `~/hgrc` or `~/.hgrc`. Make sure you know which one is right for you.

In your `mercurial.ini` or `hgrc` file, add the following:

```
[paths]
ssh = ssh -C -i ~/.ssh/bb_rsa
[ui]
ssh = ssh -C -i ~/.ssh/bb_rsa
```

One or both will do the trick for you.

After that, all of your git commands will use the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key, and all your hg commands will use the `~/.ssh/bb_rsa` key.